# How would you send repeating HTTP requests in Swift?

Tags: swift, rest, http, httprequest

I am currently creating an application that gets OHLC (open, high, low, close) financial data from an http request every ten seconds.

My functionality for the http request is contained in a completion handler of the http request like so:

```swift
HTTPRequest.requestOHLC(symbol: "XBTUSD") {ohclData in
            //do something
}
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to send repeat requests in the background

I have tried setting up while loop with a 10 second delay like so:

```swift
while(true) {
            HTTPRequest.requestOHLC(symbol: "XBTUSD"){ ohclData in
                //do something      
            }
            sleep(10)
}
```

This doesn't work, I believe because either the HTTP request is asynchronous or the sleep function does more than I understand.
If anyone knows the proper way to do this, it would be very helpful as I am quite new to using internet protocols. This seems like it should be a fairly easy thing to do.
The way this application is being used, while the current view controller is open the http request needs to constantly be being sent and stop sending as soon as the view controller changes

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work?" Is this an iOS app?  What's the code for requestOHLC?

Comment: @NobodyNada Yes this is for iOS. HTTP request never seems to get called when in the while loop. The code for requestOHLC is calling the HTTP request method in the Alamofire library and returning my own structure containing a set of double variables, I don't think this is the problem as the code works fine outside the loop

Comment: Where is the loop?  Is it running on the main thread, in a callback from something, on a background dispatch queue, or what?

Comment: @NobodyNada At the minute, I am just testing so it is at the end of viewDidLoad() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the minute, I am just testing so it is at the end of viewDidLoad() function

That's likely your problem.  `sleep` simply pauses the current thread for a specified number of seconds, and blocking the main thread is a bad idea.  The main thread is your app's main event loop, and if this thread is blocked your app cannot respond to events and will appear frozen.  Your network requests are likely waiting on the main event loop, which is never able to handle them because it is stuck waiting for `viewDidLoad` to finish.

The best solution to this problem is usually `Timer`, which can run code after a time interval has elapsed.  Here's an example:

```
// In your view controller:
var ohlcTimer: Timer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //...

    ohlcTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true) { timer in
        HTTPRequest.requestOHLC(symbol: "XBTUSD"){ ohclData in
            //do something      
        }
    }
    ohlcTimer!.fire() //cause the timer to fire once now -- it's first scheduled firing will happen in 10 seconds
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    ohlcTimer?.invalidate()
    ohlcTimer = nil
}
```